# Chrome extension: cannot communicate from web page to chrome extension (Receiving end does not exist)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My web page has been injected with the following script, which is running:

```
console.log("Injected script is running");
console.log(extensionID);
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID, {test: test}, function(response) {

});
```

where extensionID is the extension ID of my extension.

When this happens, I get the following error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

My understanding is that this is occurring because the message isn't going anywhere, or it can't connect to the extension, or something.

It is extremely unclear how I am supposed to listen for this. I am trying to follow the tutorial at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging but it is extremely unclear at describing on which page specific code blocks are supposed to be.

Am I supposed to listen in a background page? Or in a content script?

I want to get the message to be received by the content script.

Adding the following listener to either my background page, or my content script, does not work:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("background.js got a message")
        console.log(request);
        console.log(sender);
        sendResponse("bar");
    }
);
```

I have read and attempted to implement several tutorials describing this, but have never managed to pass a message from the page to the extension.

Comment: Your background script should use onMessageExternal, and your manifest.json must be edited, it seems to be clearly stated in [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) section of the documentation.

Comment: I have the same issue and it's not "clearly stated" to me either. Why should we use the external connection when it's still one site with background script (sending the message) and content script (receiving/responding). For which scenario should the [Simple one-time requests](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) work? Does it make sense to follow [this fix](https://www.bennettnotes.com/post/fix-receiving-end-does-not-exist/)? Thank you @wOxxOm for any help

Comment: Simple messaging is "to send a single message to another part of your extension" which is pretty clear to me: a content script is such a part, for example. Conversely, a web site script is not a part of the extension so to receive its messages, the external messaging mechanism should be used as described in "Sending messages from web pages" section.